# How to tag a friend in message with a photo-uploading

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags

I found an app on facebook which interests me. - https://apps.facebook.com/line_event
Basically, the app creates an album for users to upload a picture with a message. What surprised me was that. There is an @friend-tag in the message. As I know. There isn't any available api which can make an @friend-tag in message.

Does there anyone have any idea how this app do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Graph API ... you can add tag to photo 
see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

tags

Create

You can create a tag on the photo by issuing an HTTP POST request to the tags connection, PHOTO_ID/tags.

Note: This feature is intended to help users tag their friends in real photos. You should not use this feature to encourage users to tag their friends if their friends are not actually in that photo, or to tag friends in composite photos. If your app is found to be encouraging this behavior, your usage of this feature may be disabled.

Comment: I've tried this api. Unfortunately, It seems can only add a with-tag but what I meant was adding a @friend-tag in message.

Comment: Can we add tags when creating a comment?